# Cancel eBay order via API

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I use [CompleteSale](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/CompleteSale.html) function to mark order as completed on eBay via API. What is the way to cancel existing order on eBay via API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [AddDispute](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddDispute.html). It can be used to cancel single line orders.

It takes `TransactionId` **and** `ItemID` *OR* `OrderLineItemID` (concatenation of `ItemID` and `TransactionID`, with a hyphen in between these two ID [`OrderLineItemID = ItemID + "-" + OrderLineItemID`]). Presumably, you can call it multiple times to cancel multiple lines. I am not 100% sure though.

Sample from [Ebay's customer help](https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1612/~/canceling-transaction-request-via-api).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddDisputeRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Version>673</Version>
  <DisputeReason>TransactionMutuallyCanceled</DisputeReason>
  <DisputeExplanation>BuyerNoLongerWantsItem</DisputeExplanation>  
  <ItemID>140451132057</ItemID>
  <TransactionID>0</TransactionID>
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken> xxx</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
</AddDisputeRequest>
```